# Gensim Self Trained embedding load

Tags: python, gensim

There are two ways to load in pretrained word embeddings, those who are compiled in C and the other in python. I have self trained embeddings in python which are loaded in with:

`model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('transcript-vectors.pickle')`

But when I go to load them into a word dictionary ( the same way I would with a pretrained embeddings from a third party ) it errors out since it does not have the same methods as the other load.

```
embeddings_index = dict()
for word in model.wv.vocab:
    embeddings_index[word] = model.word_vec(word)
print('Loaded %s vectors' % len(embeddings_index))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-c1e5d21d49af> in <module>()
  1 embeddings_index = dict()
  2 for word in model.wv.vocab:
----> 3     embeddings_index[word] = model.word_vec(word)
  4 print('Loaded %s vectors' % len(embeddings_index))

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'word_vec'
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation  of `gensim.models.Word2Vec()`, there isn't any method defined by `word_vec()`. So you might wanna use the following: `embeddings_index[word] = model.wv[word]`

Answer (score 1):

I read some other notebooks I had using the pretrained embeddings, if they are not trained in C then it is required to use model.wv[word] as an index rather than the word_vec() function.

So the correct loop:

```
embeddings_index = dict()
for word in model.wv.vocab: #model.wv[word] | model.word_vec(word)
    embeddings_index[word] = model.wv[word]
print('Loaded %s vectors' % len(embeddings_index))
```

@Soumitri Chilakamarri further confirmed this in his comment.

Comment: We need that for checking the coverage of the embedding:

`code`
          embeddings_index = dict()
          for word in word2vec_model.wv.vocab:
          embeddings_index[word] = word2vec_model.wv.word_vec(word)
          print('Loaded %s vectors' % len(embeddings_index))
          oov = check_embedding_coverage(vocab, embeddings_index)  #keyed vectors